# fitting an inverse gaussian distribution to data in R

Tags: r, gaussian, mle

Im trying to use the fitdist function in R to fit data to three different distributions by maximum likelihood to compare them. Lognormal and Weibull work fine, but I am struggling with Inverse Gaussian. 
I need to specify starting values, however when I do I get an error message.

```
fw<-fitdist(claims,"weibull") WORKS
fln<-fitdist(claims,"lnorm") WORKS
fig<-fitdist(claims,"invgauss",start=list(mu=0,lambda=1)) DOES NOT WORK
```

Error: 'The pinvgauss function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero and not raise an error'

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried other starting values? I don't believe mu=0 makes sense.

Comment: Both parameters must be greater than zero in invgauss. Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution

Comment: I see. But even when I put higher values than 0, I get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I was working with a similar issue and found the issue was with how I labeled my start values. The actuar library I was working with required the labels "mean" and "shape" on the values. The following code provided me a solution:

```
library(actuar)
library(fitdistrplus)
fig <- fitdist(claims, "invgauss", start = list(mean = 5, shape = 1))
```

Comment: How did you come up with the parameters in the starting argument?

Answer (score 0):

**The package [fitdistrplus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/fitdistrplus_vignette.html) relies on preloaded statistical functions**. For instance, I want to fit an inverse normal distribution and choose `SuppDists` out of its many implementations. Then I load `library(SuppDists)` first, and fit `fitdistrplus::fitdist` next. The full snippet:

```
install.packages("fitdistrplus")
install.packages("SuppDists")

library(fitdistrplus)
library(SuppDists)

# shelf-live data
X = c(24, 24, 26, 26, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 35, 41, 42, 43, 47, 48, 48, 48, 50, 52, 54, 55, 57, 57, 57, 57, 61)

fit <- fitdist(X, "invGauss", start = list( nu = 30, lambda = 10.5))
fit
# Parameters:
#         estimate Std. Error
# nu      42.88774    2.50325
# lambda 484.29802  134.32093
```

reproduces the shelf-life data example from [The Inverse Gaussian Distribution and its Statistical Application-A Review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984691).